# Writing a script with the cmd prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to make a script that will place a list (in a .csv file) of processes that are running that take up more than 10 mb of RAM and shows the time + date the script was run. My teacher did this during his lecture but I can't remember how he did it. Just trying to figure out how to be better at IT.

So my question is, can anyone help me with this? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You could always ask your teacher to explain what they did and how it works, sorry to direct you back in that direction but you'll probably get more out of their explanation than you'll get here with the straight answer.

Comment: @Lazarus, if you do what he suggests, then make sure to come back to this question and give us the answer :)

Comment: @Lazarus, I think you've missed the point entirely of SO.

Comment: @Earlz Why should I do this for him? I have given him good, sound advice. Referring him to a source of the knowledge I **know** has the information he requires, exactly the same as pointing him to a web page with the answer. Lastly, it's not even a programming question. So, @Keng, **who** has missed the point of SO?

Comment: @Lazarus: This is a place for asking questions and getting *relevant* answers. Maybe that class ended and he can't contact the teacher any more. You *don't* know if he can get back to that source. 

For any question here, there is always an answer somewhere else, so by your logic, nobody should ask anything on SO.

Comment: @Lazarus, I was talking about you in third person. I meant if Josh follows Lazarus' advice, then Josh should come back and post the answer that Josh got from his teacher.

Comment: @Earlz, sorry, your text read completely the other way. Thanks for clearing it up. ;)

Comment: @user151841, this is the place to ask ***relevant*** questions and get ***relevant*** answers. So, is the question ***relevant***? The statement "My teacher" implies a certain continuity as opposed to "The teacher", "The lecturer", "The presenter". It's attention to detail that makes good developers.

Comment: @Lazarus, YOU...that's who.  You're on a question and answer site to say go somewhere else to ask quesitons is redonkulus!

Comment: @Keng, this is a **Programming** question and answer site and the question isn't programming related. It's not Yahoo Answers, perhaps you should read the FAQ before casting aspersions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Lazarus, since when is batch file scripting NOT programming?  Tell you what, why don't you get a moderator in here and ask them if this is programming related or not.

Comment: @Keng, since when is this batch file scripting? This is running tasklist at the command line, is typing "word.exe" at the command line batch file scripting too? You are clutching at straws here.

Comment: @Lazarus, are you TRYING to be obtuse or did you just not read the question?...maybe you didn't read it....read it, then comment.
"I'm trying to make a script..."

Comment: @Keng, which you wrote for him and have tried really hard to make it look difficult and worthy of being a question here. I'm glad that you are happy to do the "Do this for me" requests, it saves others the effort but please don't try to get all holier than thou over it. It's a bad question, it's not a programming question (not disrespecting batch scripting, when it's more than just @echo off, docmd.exe --someflags > output). Every SysAdmin I know does this kind of thing and would call it SysAdmin not programming.

Comment: @Keng, you know what... if you think this is programming then fine. Let's agree to differ and hopefully our paths will never cross again.

Comment: @Lazarus, "...don't try to get all holier than thou over it." I refer the right honorable gentleman to the comment HE made 2 hours ago. Is your problem that batch scripting isn't programming or that it's a homework quesition? If the later then just tag it, vote to close and move on. But to say scripting isn't programming and scripting questions don't belong here is not only wrong, it flies in the face of everything Jeff and Joel have been saying on the podcast since DAY 1. "...hopefully our paths will never cross again." It's a big world but I doubt it.

Comment: @Keng, simple question, what do you think the OP learnt from your response? Did they learn some programming skills?

Comment: @Lazarus, depends on what in the world an "OP" is. BTW: you may also want to define "programming"   BTW: jump in on the discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/should-the-batch-file-programming-questions-be-moved-from-so-to-sf

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in PowerShell like so:

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.PM -gt 10MB} | 
    Export-Csv "memhogs-$(Get-Date -uf %Y%m%d%H%M).csv
```

or using aliases

```
gps | ?{$_.PM -gt 10MB} | epcsv "memhogs-$(Get-Date -uf %Y%m%d%H%M).csv
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
set var=%DATE% %TIME%
echo %var%>c:\tasklist2.csv
tasklist /fi "memusage gt 10000" /fo csv>>c:\tasklist2.csv
```

in the real world you don't get Vista or Win7....unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'tasklist' command and then filter by memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Windows operating systems now ship with an alternate shell to cmd called PowerShell

Here is how you would do it in Powershell.

```
ps | where-object { $_.workingset -gt 10000000 } | Out-File c:\list.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `tasklist` command eg

```
tasklist /FI  "Memusage gt 10000" /NH
```

use `date /T` or `time /T` to create date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the date to the filename here.

```
set var=%DATE% %TIME%
set var1=%DATE%
set var1=%var1:/=%
set var1=%var1:~-8%
echo %var%>c:\tasklist%var1%.csv
tasklist /fi "memusage gt 10000" /fo csv>>c:\tasklist%var1%.csv
```